# In which order are the conditions tested in a Sqlite query?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Let's say I have 1,000,000 rows in a table, and I do this query (using `sqlite3` module in Python):

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE editdist3(description, "hello world") < 500 
                                   AND price > 3707 AND price < 3800' )
```

Obviously computing the `editdist3` edit distance / [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) on 1 million rows will be very costly for CPU!

**Question:** how to make sure that the filtering condition `3707 < price < 3800` is applied **before** computing the Levenshtein distance?

Should I do two queries: a primary query to pre-filter this `3707 < price < 3800` condition, and then only, a second query computing `editdist3` on the (a lot less) remaining rows? Or is there a way to do this in one single query?

Note: this question is a poor-wording (my bad!) version of this [better question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49861513/1422096).

Answer (score 0):

If you have index on `ID`, sql engine will use it to find the description and then apply the distance to only those elements.

The best should be create the index with `(ID, description)`

```
create index idx on mytable (ID, description);
```

You can test it by checking the [explain plan](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Comment: I think my question was too specific with "ID" column @JuanCarlosOropeza, I modified to a more general condition `3707 < x < 3800`  (here I gave example with `price` but it could be anything else).

Comment: My answer would be the same, create an index for price. And again you can check using explain analyze

Comment: What do you mean by index on price? Could you give a code example showing your solution with index? Thank you in advance.

Comment: [SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE INDEX](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html)

Comment: you mean dont know how create index? check edit and this one http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql