# Does SQLite optimize a query with multiple AND conditions in the WHERE clause?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, lazy-evaluation

In SQL databases (I use Python+Sqlite), how to make sure that, if we have 1 million rows, the query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfunction(description) < 500 AND column2 < 1000
                           [-----------------------------]   [--------------]
                               high-CPU cost condition         easy-to-test 
                              requiring 100 µs per test         condition
```

is optimized so that the 1st condition (CPU-expensive) **is only tested** if the easy-to-test second condition is already True? (since it's a logical `AND`, is it a lazy `AND`?)

Example:

- if the 1st condition is always tested, it would require 1 million x 100 µs = 100 seconds!
- if the 2nd condition is tested first, then only 5000 items would be pre-filtered (in my use-case), and then, applying the 1st condition would be very fast.

Note:

- column2 is not necessary an ID, it could be something else
- in my use case, `myfunction` involves Levenshtein distance computation

Comment: I believe if you change the order of "and" conditions you will achieve the optimization you desire.

Comment: I'd need to see an `EXPLAIN PLAN` to believe that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Updated answer based on comments and subsequent testing.)*

The actual answer to your question

> how to make sure that, if we have 1 million rows, the query ... is optimized so that the 1st condition (CPU-expensive) is only tested if the easy-to-test second condition is already True?

depends on

- the actual conditions in the WHERE clause, and
- how clever the SQLite query optimizer is in estimating the cost of those conditions.

A simple test should tell you whether your query would be sufficiently "optimized" for your needs. The good news is that SQLite *will* perform the easy (inexpensive) condition first, at least under certain circumstances.

For a test table "mytable"

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    description TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
    column2 INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT mytable_PK PRIMARY KEY (column2)
);
```

containing a million rows

```
description  column2
-----------  -------
row000000          0
row000001          1
row000002          2
...
row999999     999999
```

the Python test code

```python
import sqlite3
import time

log_file_spec = r'C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\log_file.txt'

def myfunc(thing):
    with open(log_file_spec, 'a') as log:
        log.write('HODOR\n')
    return(int(thing[-6:]))


with open(log_file_spec, 'w'):
    pass  # just empty the file
cnxn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\__tmp\SQLite\test.sqlite')
cnxn.create_function("myfunction", 1, myfunc)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
t0 = time.time()
sql = """\
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM mytable
WHERE myfunction(description) < 500 AND column2 < 1000
"""
crsr.execute(sql)
num_rows = crsr.fetchone()[0]
print(f"{num_rows} rows found in {(time.time() - t0):.1f} seconds")

cnxn.close()
```

returns

```
500 rows found in 1.2 seconds
```

and counting the lines in log_file.txt we see

```
C:\Users\Gord>find /C "HODOR" Desktop\log_file.txt

---------- DESKTOP\LOG_FILE.TXT: 1000
```

indicating that our function was only called one thousand times, not one million times. SQLite has clearly applied the `column2 < 1000` first, and then applied the `myfunction(description) < 500` condition on the subset of rows from the first condition.

---

*(Original "off the cuff" answer.)*

The actual answer to your question depends on how clever the query optimizer is. A simple test should tell you whether your query would be sufficiently "optimized" for your needs.

However, you do have a couple of options if your tests find that your original approach is too slow:

**Option 1: Try doing the simple comparison "first"**

Changing the order might affect the query plan, e.g.

```sql
... WHERE <easy_condition> AND <expensive_condition>
```

might turn out to be faster than

```sql
... WHERE <expensive_condition> AND <easy_condition>
```

**Option 2: Try forcing the order using a subquery**

Again, depending on the cleverness of the query optimizer

```sql
SELECT easy.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column2 < 1000) easy
WHERE myfunction(easy.description) < 500
```

might apply the inexpensive condition first, then apply the expensive condition on the resulting subset of rows. (However, a comment indicates that SQLite is too sophisticated to fall for that ploy.)

Comment: SQLite does [subquery flattening](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#subquery_flattening).

Comment: @CL. I'm new to this, what is the implication of the fact you mention? (Does this make Option1 or Option2 or both non-working? Or does it improve something?)

Comment: @GordThompson Is there a way to be 100% sure that, in Option 1, changing the order of conditions really changes something? (`might turn out to be faster than ...`)

Comment: @Basj - You could try passing both variants to [EXPLAIN](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) and see if the results are different. You could also try running them against test data to see if the execution times differ significantly.

Comment: @Basj The page I linked to explains this.

Comment: @CL. I saw in your linked page that the nested SELECT will be flattened to finally a single SELECT, right, but what is the conclusion of this flattening about GordThompson's answer given here? (Thanks in advance, as I'm not SQL expert, I don't want to draw wrong conclusions).

Comment: @Basj After flattening, you have a single query with two AND-connected conditions (i.e., what you started with).

Comment: @CL. ok I understand so this means we're back to the initial point because of flatenning? If so, what solution would you use (if you have an answer, it would be helpful)?

Comment: @CL. - Thanks for the tip re: subquery flattening. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your updated version @GordThompson. Based on your benchmark, I also did [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49885911/1422096).

Answer (score 4):

One way that you can force the order of execution is using a `case` expression.  In general, SQL optimizers can re-arrange operations, the one exception is `case`.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (CASE WHEN column2 >= 1000  OR column2 IS NULL THEN 0
            WHEN myfunction(description) < 500 THEN 1
       END) = 1;
```

Generally, `case` expressions are discouraged in `WHERE` clauses . . . one major reason is that they impede optimization.  In this case, that is a good thing.

Comment: Wouldn't `CASE WHEN column2 < 1000 THEN 1
            WHEN myfunction(description) < 500 THEN 1 END` return 1 in the case `column2 < 1000` or also in the case `myfunction(description) < 500`? If so, it's a mathematical union (OR) and not AND? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Basj Yes; the function belongs in the first THEN clause.

Comment: @CL. What do you mean by "belong in the first THEN", and why is it so? It seems to me that `myfunction` only appears in the *second* WHEN case, please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Basj . . . You are correct.  I usually encounter this problem with `OR` rather than `AND`.  For some reason, I would expect any SQL optimizer to handle the `AND` case correctly, even SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite will happily reorder AND-connected expressions whenever it feels like it. So while rewriting the query to check `column2` first appears to work in the current version, there is no guarantee.

The query optimizer assumes that speed is determined mainly by disk I/O, so it estimates the cost of both conditions to be the same.
Cost estimates are influenced by indexes, and by [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) statistics (which work only for indexed data).
So the easiest way to speed up this query (and probably most other queries you will use) is to create an index on `column2`:

```sql
CREATE INDEX my_little_index ON mytable(column2);
```

If you do not want to use an index for some reason, you have to use a construct that the query optimizer cannot optimize away. A CASE expression as shown in Gordon's answer would work just fine. In the general case, move the first condition into a subquery and prevent [subquery flattening](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#flattening) by breaking one of the listed rules; adding a dummy LIMIT clause to both queries usually is easiest:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM mytable
      WHERE column2 < 1000
      LIMIT -1)
WHERE myfunction(description) < 500
LIMIT -1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to be sure to understand: 1) how to use `CREATE INDEX my_little_index ON mytable(column2);` in the subsequent query `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfunction(description) < 500 AND column2 < 1000` to make sure the index is *used* indeed to optimize the query?    2) Does it require `column2` has unique values (no duplicates) to make an index?

Comment: @Basj - No, the index on `column2` does not necessarily need to be unique in order for the query optimizer to take advantage of it. However, depending on the index statistics it *might* decide that a non-unique index does not offer a significant advantage over a table scan. However, in the vast majority of cases the index will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @GordThompson's answer, here is a benchmark between:

```
(1)  SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col2 < 1000 AND myfunction(col1) < 500
```

vs.

```
(2)  SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfunction(col1) < 500 AND col2 < 1000
```

---

#### Test (1) (easy-to-test condition first): 1.02 seconds

```
import sqlite3, time, random

def myfunc(x):
    time.sleep(0.001) # wait 1 millisecond for each call of this function
    return x

# Create database
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
db.create_function("myfunction", 1, myfunc)
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE mytable (col1 INTEGER, col2 INTEGER)');
for i in range(10*1000):
    a = random.randint(0,1000)
    c.execute('INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?, ?)', (a, i));

# Do the evil query
t0 = time.time()
c.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col2 < 1000 AND myfunction(col1) < 500')
for e in c.fetchall():
    print e
print "Elapsed time: %.2f" % (time.time() - t0)
```

Result: 1.02 seconds, it means that `myfunc` has been called max 1000 times, i.e. **not for all the 10k rows**.

---

#### Test (2) (Slow-to-compute condition first): 10.05 seconds

Idem with:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfunction(col1) < 500 AND col2 < 1000')
```

instead.

Result: 10.05 seconds, it means that `myfunc` has been called ~ 10k times, i.e. **for all the 10k rows**, even those for which the condition `col2 < 1000` is not True.

---

Global conclusion: **Sqlite does lazy evaluation for `AND`, i.e. the easy condition has to be written first like this:**

```
... WHERE <easy_condition> AND <expensive_condition>
```

Comment: Note that your test table does not have an index on `col2` so both WHERE conditions require a table scan. That explains why my test was fast even when the expensive condition was listed first in the WHERE clause. (With no indexes available, the SQLite query optimizer apparently sees both conditions as being equally expensive, so it doesn't bother fiddling with the order in which the conditions are evaluated.)